# can not read sheet with gspread in using python 3

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets-api, gspread

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']
creds = 
ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('creds.json',scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

print(client)
```

I am able to create a client object but when I try to read any sheet I get this useless error

> gspread.exceptions.RequestError: (401, '401: b\'\n\nToken invalid - AuthSub token has wrong scope\n\n\n
>
> ## Token invalid - AuthSub token has wrong scope
>
> \n
>
> ### Error 401
>
> \n\n\n\'')

Comment: Do you have the same issue when you change the scope to: ``https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds`` ?